# How to do memcpy an enum value into buffer

Tags: c++

I can copy regular integers as bytes into a buffer, but I cannot do that with an Enum value (second line in `main`). Other than copying the Enum value into an int and then do `memcpy` that int into the buffer, is there a better way?

Actually, it does not have to be `memcpy`. I just need an elegant way to put the enum value as bytes into the buffer.

```
typedef uint8_t byte;

enum MyEnum :uint16_t
{
    AAA = 1,
    BBB = 2,
    CCC = 3
};

const uint16_t aaa = 0x1234;
byte buffer[10];

int main()
{
    memcpy(buffer, (uint8_t*)&aaa, sizeof(aaa)); //works
    memcpy(buffer, (uint8_t*)&AAA, sizeof(AAA)); //error
```

Comment: There are two sides to C++. Run time and compile time. `AAA` lives in the compile time domain so there is no `address` of `AAA` that you can access at run time.

Comment: @lakeweb I see. But then, what is the elegant way to put that value into the buffer?

Comment: The simplest way is just to make a temporary variable of type `MyEnum`.  `MyEnum tmp = AAA; memcpy(buffer, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));`.  The compiler will probably optimize it into a simple memory store.  It can also be done with a compound literal instead of a temporary variable, but the syntax is uglier.

Comment: `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(buf + 1) = AAA;` But I don't like that kind of stuff. And, of course, the `+1` puts the value in the second position.

Comment: This is very similar to `memcpy(buffer, (uint8_t*)&1, sizeof(1))`

Comment: Hi @molbdnilo How do you make that work? `&1` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @lakeweb Why is "+1" needed? I tried that, and that resulted in AAA to be copied to `buffer[1]` and `buffer[2]`. I wanted it to be copied to `buffer[0]` and `buffer[1]`.

Comment: You don't need the `+1`, it was just an example. But you have a `byte` buffer and an `int` is typically 4 bytes. So if you just want to copy the enum as a byte value. `*reinterpret_cast<int8_t*>(buf) = AAA;`

Comment: Actually, that code is filling `buffer[1]` to `buffer[4]`. `buffer[3]` to `buffer[4]` were filled with `0`, which was not I wanted. Because I only wanted to write two bytes (uint16_t). I changed `int*` with `uint16_t*` and then it only affected two bytes.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea DV! And @molbdnilo I get your comment now, sorry for being so staunchy.